# How many xml http requests is too much for a pc to handle?

Tags: javascript, apache, xmlhttprequest, mediawiki

I'm running **mediawiki** on an **apache** on a regular pc running vista (don't know the specific specs, but a regular pc, one year old, nothing special).

Edit: I'm guessing something like duo core 2 2 giga hertz processor, broadband connection (500 kb/s at least) and most of the time the requests will be sent through LAN (but sometimes through the internet)

I want to use the mediawiki api to send a lot of requests to this server. I'm talking  thousands of requests every few seconds at worst case. (A lot of these requests may repeat themselves, I guess some sort of cache would help)

Will the server handle this, or do I need a stronger/dedicated computer?

Edit: I'm not looking for specific yes/no, but what configuration of computer will support how many request per second.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a joke? You ask whether the server will handle this without actually describing any parameter of this server and even if you did it would be a subjective question.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on serverfault?

Comment: @Joe, yes this definitely belongs to http://serverfault.com as it is not programming related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is entirely Dependant on the Server, PC hardware, software, and Internet connection.

If you want to find out, run some tests, when your machine stops working, you have reached the limit.

Comment: I can't run tests because I haven't built the application that sends the requests, and this may have implications to how I build it. So I need someone with experience to tell me if these are reasonable amounts or not.

Comment: You can use Apache's "ab" as a simple tool to measure the performance.

Comment: Run something like: ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://localhost/ . This will send 1000 request through 10 parallel connections. Of course you can change the url to your script and add some extra params if required.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the requests coming from - LAN, internet? What connection speed?

You might be able to use [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) to run some tests against your API and see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds helpful, I'll try, but still looking for general order of magnitude of requests this kind of setup can handle.